# Are all prophets alive in their graves?

Tags: prophets, grave

Is there any reference which evidence that all prophets are alive in their graves. When ever we visit graveyard its common practice to say 'Assalam o Alaikum Ya ehlal qaboor' and its a common asumption that they respond it with an answer 'Wa alaikum salam'.

Is that true ? If its true are they alive too ? If they all respond then does it mean that they are all alive in their graves ?

Sorry for my poor knowledge, I have asked it from different Imams of different mosques and their view have a conflict.

Answer (score 2):

Not just all prophets, everyone is alive, just not alive on earth.

**From Qur'an:**

> [Ali 'Imran: 169:](https://quran.com/3/169)
>
> *وَلَا تَحْسَبَنَّ الَّذِينَ قُتِلُوا فِي سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ أَمْوَاتًا ۚ بَلْ أَحْيَاءٌ عِندَ رَبِّهِمْ يُرْزَقُونَ*
>
> And do not ever reckon the ones who have been killed in the way of Allah (as) dead; no indeed, **they are alive** in the Providence of their Lord, by Him provided.

**Salaam at the end of Salat:**

> *السلام علیک ایها النبی و رحمه الله و برکاته*
>
> Peace be unto you O  prophet and the mercy and all blessings of God

The above shows that the prophet while not being a martyr is alive. If he was to be assumed dead then we should have said:  *السلام عليه و رحمت الله*

**Narrated from Imam Kazim:**

> *«انه روی فی الکافی باسناده عن ابی الحسن الکاظم علیه السلام انه قال فی*
> *قصة لمنکری المعاد من الامم الماضیة فاحدث الله فیهم الاحلام و لم یکن*
> *قبل ذلک فاتوا نبیهم فاخبروه بما راو و ما انکروا من ذلک فقال: ان الله*
> *تعالی اراد ان یحتج علیکم بهذا هکذا تکون ارواحهم اذا متم و ان بلیت*
> *ابدانکم تصیر الارواح الی عقاب تبعث الابدان »*
>
> Al-Kafi Vol. 1 Pg. 110 [...Imam Kazim was talking about the previous
> nations who were denying the judgement day: Allah had placed
> 'sleeping' among them while they were asking from their prophets to
> show them examples of what will happen after death]
>
> Allah has ordained to reason with you using 'sleep', as your souls
> will depart your bodies just as they do when you go sleep and by the
> will of Allah they will be joined with your body again to see the
> divine retribution

Do we do die will we go to sleep? No. Do we die die (like we are non-existent like what the atheists say) when we are put into our graves? Again no, it's just beginning of our *real* life.

**Narrated from Prophet Muhammad:**

> *النَّاسِ نِیَامٌ فَإِذَا مَاتُوا انْتَبَهُوا*
>
> People are sleep, once they die they are awaken.

Comment: Isn't the quoted ayah about martyrs?

Comment: @Uma Yes, you're right. See my edit

Comment: @Honey do they answer to our salam when we go to graveyard ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad Do the angels write down our deeds? Is the Satan enticing us? Is Allah answering our prayers? Is the creation [supplicating Allah](https://quran.com/61/1)(There are many more verse just search: یسبح له ما فی السماوات) ?
I'm sure you'll answer all with a Yes...but none we see nor hear. To answer your question specifically, yes they answer, but we don't hear. If we become purified of our sins, then perhaps we can see, hear more things.

Comment: Alright I know this fact that we cant hear. @Honey

Comment: @Honey that first ayah is about martyrs.....

Comment: @Casanova see my edit